# What is going wrong when using getchar for my C program?

Tags: c

Hello folks it's my first question here :)

I just started studying CS in Berlin and tried to write a prog on my own which prints every charakter of a string literally in the terminal. And it works fine when defining the word which has to be printed in the C-Code.

```
int main () {
    
printf("Type in a word:\n");

    char wort[] = "raffiniert";
    int i = 0;

    if (wort[i] == i)
    {
        printf("No word typed in!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    while (wort[i] != '\0')
    {
        printf("%c \n", wort[i]);        
        i++;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

But when trying to implement getchar, so u can type in the console, not in the code, it fails. Regardless of how much other things I tried.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
int main ()
{

    printf("Type in a word:\n");
    int i = 0;
    char wort;

    wort = getchar();

    if ((wort = getchar()) == i)
    {
        printf("No word typed in!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    while ((wort = getchar()) != '\0')
    {
        printf("%c \n", wort);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My problems are:

1. The program does not terminate automatically after printing out.
2. The first time typing in a word, it's printed uncompletely. It starts to print completely after the first time.

Could y'all at least give me advices what to correct?

Thanks and stay in good health.

Comment: `while ((wort = getchar()) != '\0')` That won't work. `getchar` never returns the NUL character. Look for the `\n` (newline) character instead. Also, `getchar` returns an `int` not a `char`. That is important if you want to be able to test for the `EOF` which is returned at the end of the stream (ctrl-d on most terminals).

Comment: `getchar` will return '\0', if it reads a '\0'.

Comment: @kaylum Ctrl-D on Unix-like systems (but it's configurable), Ctrl-Z on Windows.

Comment: You want `#include <stdio.h>`, not `#include "stdio.h"`. And I don't think you need `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: Always compile with *warnings enabled*, and **do not** accept code until it *compiles without warning*. To enable warnings add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to your `gcc/clang` compile string (also consider adding `-Wshadow` to warn on shadowed variables). For **VS** (`cl.exe` on windows), use `/W3`. All other compilers will have similar options. Read and understand each warning -- then go fix it. The warnings will identify any problems, and the exact line on which they occur.

Comment: Thanks guys! Appreciate ur help!

Answer (score 0):

"The program does not terminate automatically after printing out."

That's because your loop condition is incorrect.  You want to check if `getchar()` returns EOF.

"The first time typing in a word, it's printed uncompletely. It starts to print completely after the first time."

That is because you are discarding the first two characters of input.  You have 2 calls to `getchar()` where you basically discard the result.  Just do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int wort;      /* Must be int to compare with EOF */
    int i = 0;

    while( (wort = getchar()) != EOF ){
        putchar(wort);
        i += 1;
    }
    if( i == 0 ){
        fprintf(stderr, "No word typed in!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```